# Why is my classification tree is showing only one node, and how to resolve this issue?

Tags: random-forest, decision-trees, multiclass-classification, matlab

I also asked here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/287587/reason-of-getting-only-one-node-while-implementing-classification-tree-in-matlab

Hello, I have $N=1520=19*80$ samples, each of which are $p=1764$-dimensional. So $N < p$ here. I want to perform a $19$-class classification of these samples. The training data consists of $80$ samples from each of the $19$ classes. I performed classification tree in matlab (sorry but this is the only language I know well) using fitctree$(X,Y)$ where $X=$matrix of covariates of size $N \times p$, $Y=$ vector of responses of size $N \times 1$.I'm getting only one node each time.

Just to see if the problem solves when I reduce the number of features significantly, I tried to take the first $100$ features by $X=X(:, 1:100)$, but still got only one node.

Next, my knn and naive Bayes classifiers are also predicting all samples to be in one class, just like the tree above.

What could be the problem, and how could I possibly solve it? Am I making a syntactical mistake?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You want a 19-class classification, but fitctree is a binary classifier (2 class).  I don't use matlab for ML, so correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but it seems fitctree could classify the samples into any number of classes. See for example, https://fr.mathworks.com/help/stats/classification-trees-and-regression-trees.html, and here they classify the species in Fisher's iris dataset into 3 classes-setosa, virginica and versicolor.

Comment: can you show some sample data or code?

Comment: @oW_: I'll be glad to. Just a quick question, the data had 1520 samples, and 1764 features. How can I show it here in a compact way?

Comment: good question.. maybe upload a sample on github or somewhere where people can take a quick look. the code will probably be more helpful...

Comment: @oW_: Yes let me try-I've an account in GitHub and I know what it is, it's just that I'dnever uploaded anything there yet. May I ask: is it normal uploading like uploading a CV to a site etc.? I hear the terms like fork or Gitpull etc., but I unfortunately don't have much idea.